# How do you implement search over static content within cshtml files

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am using asp.net core and Razor - and as it is a help system I would like to implement some kind of search facility to bring back a list of results hyperlinked based on the search terms.

I would like the search to iterate essentially over the content contained within the

and  tags and then link this to the appropriate page/view.

What is the best way to do this?

I'm not even sure how you get a handle on the actual content of your own cshtml pages and then go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is *far* too broad. However, I can provide you some pointers.

First, you need to determine what you're actually wanting to surface and where that data lives. Your question says "static web pages", but then you mention `.cshtml`. Traditionally, when it comes to creating your own search, you're going to have access to some particular dataset (tables in a database, for example). It's *much* simpler to search across the more structured data than the end result of it being dumped in various and sundry places over a web page.

Search engines like Google only index in this way because they typically don't have access to the raw data (although some amount of "access" can be granted via things like JSON-LD and other forms of Schema.org markup). In other words, they actually read from the web page out of necessity, because that's what they have to work with. It's certainly not the approach you would take if you have access to the data directly.

If for some reason you need to actually spider an index your own site's HTML content, then you'll essentially have to do what the big boys do: create a bot, run it on a schedule, crawl your site, link by link, downloading each document, and then parse and process it. The end result would be to create a set of structured data that you can actually query against, which is why all this is pretty much just wasted effort if you already *have* that data.

Once you have the data, however you got there, you simply query it. In the most basic of forms, you could store it in a table in a database and literally issue SQL queries against it. Your search keywords/parameters are essentially the `WHERE` of the `SELECT` statement, so you'd have to figure out a way to map the keywords/parameters you're receiving to an acceptable `WHERE` clause that achieves that.

More traditionally, you'd use an actual search engine: essentially a document database that is designed and optimized for search, and generally provides a more search-appropriate API to query against. There's lots of options in this space from roll your own to hosted SaaS solutions, and anywhere in between. Of course the cost meter goes down the more work you have to do and goes up the more out of the box it is.

One popular open-source and largely free option is Elasticsearch. It uses Lucene indexes, which it stitches to together in a clustered environment to provide failover and scale. Deployment is a beast, to say the least, though it's gotten considerably better with things like containerization and orchestration. You can stand up an Elasticsearch cluster in something like Kubernetes with relative ease, though you still will probably need to do a bit of config. Elasticsearch does also have hosted options, but you know, cost.

Comment: So I guess I'm only interested in content within <p> and <h> tags then link this to it's appropriate page/view. It does seem rather redundant to keep running the same search over the same content without caching it in some way. Some of the solutions you kindly suggested seem a bit overkill for me at the moment as there are not that many pages of content (yet).

Comment: In the end I wrote a python script that extracted meaningful text (mostly nouns) removed duplicates and linked the text to the html page and stored it in a json file. Then my search facility on the website utilised this json file to conduct it's search and display search results accordingly.  Cheers for the help Chris